# Function to append strings returning pointer/cast error

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to create a function that takes two input strings, dest and src, and appends the src string to the dest string.

Below is the current function I have. However, when I try to use it, I 
get an error stating "returning 'char' from a function without a cast." I understand that my error involves the return statement and how I'm using it as a pointer, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

```
char* strcat(char dest[], char src[]) {
    int destL = lenstr(dest);
    int srcL = lenstr(src);
    char result[destL + srcL];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < destL; i++){
        result[i] = dest[i];
    }

    for(i = destL; i < destL+srcL; i++){
        result[i] = src[i-destL];
    }

    return *result;
}
```

The lenstr function is:

```
int lenstr(char* s) {
    int len = 0;
    while(s[len++] != '\0');
    return len-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a locally declared array. Well you can, but the data may be overwritten at any time since it is no longer valid.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
char* strcat(char dest[], char src[]) {
    char * result = malloc((lenstr(dest)+lenstr(src)+1) * sizeof *result);

    // Code to copy data

    return result;
}
```

Note that `+1` is important to make room for the `\0` terminator.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to use it, I get an error stating "returning 'char' from a function without a cast."

This error simply indicates that your return value doesn't match the function declaration. In your function declaration, you have mentioned that it returns a `char *`. However, in your actual return statement, you are returning `*result` which is a dereferenced char pointer i.e. a `char`.

The second problem in your code is that you are returning an array from the function. Memory allocated using an array in a method becomes unavailable to the caller method. You need to create memory on heap and return a pointer to it and then let the caller free up the memory after usage.

Checkout the following working code:

```
char* strcat1(char dest[], char src[]) {
    int destL = lenstr(dest);
    int srcL = lenstr(src);

    char * result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (destL + srcL));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < destL; i++){
        result[i] = dest[i];
    }

    for(i = destL; i < destL+srcL; i++){
        result[i] = src[i-destL];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please make sure the caller frees up the result as shown below:

```
char * result = strcat1("hi", "ho");
printf(result);
free(result);
```